# Is there an existing PropertyGrid UITypeEditor for type "ChartColorPalette"?

Tags: propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I'm trying to write a simple property grid to allow the users to modify the colours of a Chart. By default, a Chart has a "Palette" property, which is of the enumeration type "ChartColorPalette". If the object which underlies my property grid also has a "Palette" property of the same type, I get the drop-down list of possible values. What I don't get however, is the little stripey images to the left of the value names.

Now, I can write a UITypeEditor derived class and have the "PaintValue" draw little resource bitmaps which I have culled from the screen using "Paint" or somesuch, but this seems rather tedious.

Does anyone know if there is already a type editor for the "ChartColorPalette" enumeration which I can use to get the little bitmaps ?

Comment: This is using the "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart" control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it happens, writing the UITypeEditor is not that tricky, and not that much code either.
Firstly I created a type editor that looked like this:

```
private class ChartColorPaletteEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override bool GetPaintValueSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void PaintValue(PaintValueEventArgs e)
    {
        String paletteName = e.Value.ToString();
        String baseName = this.GetType().Namespace + ".MyChart";
        ResourceManager mgr = new ResourceManager(baseName, this.GetType().Assembly);
        Bitmap bmp = mgr.GetObject(paletteName) as Bitmap;
        if (bmp != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, e.Bounds);
            bmp.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I attached this to my control property in the usual way:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(ChartColorPalette), "BrightPastel")]
[Editor(typeof(ChartColorPaletteEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
[Category("Appearance")]
[Description("The named palette to use when choosing the colour scheme for the chart series lines.")]
public ChartColorPalette Palette { get; set; }
```

Then I added a small PNG resource for each of the little palette images. I had a derived control "MyChart" which inherited from "Chart" and I added the images to that as resources (making sure to set the "Persistance" property to "Embedded in .resx" to save having to keep the PNG files about). The names of the PNG files matched the names in the ChartColorPalette enumeration.

The only issue was where to get the little 20 x 14 images from. I originally just culled them using Paint.exe but didn't like that, so I wrote some code to generate them for me. That was fairly simple, once I had found the colour values that are used by the Charting control. One subtlety is that, where there are more than 12 colours in a palette, the little bitmap uses every other colour. That code looked like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Enum.GetValues(typeof(ChartColorPalette)).OfType<ChartColorPalette>().ToList().ForEach(GeneratePNG);
  }

  static void GeneratePNG(ChartColorPalette palette)
  {
     if (palette == ChartColorPalette.None) return;

     Color[] colours = palette.GetColors();

     if (colours.Length >= 12)
     {
        colours = new Color[] { colours[0], colours[2], colours[4], colours[6], colours[8], colours[10] };
     }
     else
     {
        colours = new Color[] { colours[0], colours[1], colours[2], colours[3], colours[4], colours[5] };
     }

     using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(20, 14))
     {
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
           using (SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush(colours[0]),
                             b2 = new SolidBrush(colours[1]),
                             b3 = new SolidBrush(colours[2]),
                             b4 = new SolidBrush(colours[3]),
                             b5 = new SolidBrush(colours[4]),
                             b6 = new SolidBrush(colours[5]))
           {
              int height = bmp.Height - 2;
              gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1);
              gr.FillRectangle(b1, new Rectangle(1, 1, 3, height));
              gr.FillRectangle(b2, new Rectangle(4, 1, 3, height));
              gr.FillRectangle(b3, new Rectangle(7, 1, 3, height));
              gr.FillRectangle(b4, new Rectangle(10, 1, 3, height));
              gr.FillRectangle(b5, new Rectangle(13, 1, 3, height));
              gr.FillRectangle(b6, new Rectangle(16, 1, 3, height));
           }
        }

        String path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        path = Path.Combine(path, @"Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DataVisualization.Charting\Palette Bitmaps");

        String filename = palette.ToString() + ".png";
        bmp.Save(Path.Combine(path, filename), ImageFormat.Png);
     }
  }
}

public static class Extensions
{
  public static Color[] GetColors(this ChartColorPalette value)
  {
     switch (value)
     {
        case ChartColorPalette.Berry:
           return GetColors(0x8a2be2, 0xba55d3, 0x4169e1, 0xc71585, 0x0000ff, 0x8a2be2, 0xda70d6, 0x7b68ee, 0xc000c0, 0x0000cd, 0x800080);
        case ChartColorPalette.Bright:
           return GetColors(0x008000, 0x0000ff, 0x800080, 0x00ff00, 0xff00ff, 0x008080, 0xffff00, 0x808080, 0x00ffff, 0x000080, 0x800000, 0xff0000, 0x808000, 0xc0c0c0, 0xff6347, 0xffe4b5);
        case ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel:
           return GetColors(0x418cf0, 0xfcb441, 0xe0400a, 0x056492, 0xbfbfbf, 0x1a3b69, 0xffe382, 0x129cdd, 0xca6b4b, 0x005cdb, 0xf3d288, 0x506381, 0xf1b9a8, 0xe0830a, 0x7893be);
        case ChartColorPalette.Chocolate:
           return GetColors(0xa0522d, 0xd2691e, 0x8b0000, 0xcd853f, 0xa52a2a, 0xf4a460, 0x8b4513, 0xc04000, 0xb22222, 0xb65c3a);
        case ChartColorPalette.EarthTones:
           return GetColors(0xff8000, 0xb8860b, 0xc04000, 0x6b8e23, 0xcd853f, 0xc0c000, 0x228b22, 0xd2691e, 0x808000, 0x20b2aa, 0xf4a460, 0x00c000, 0x8fbc8b, 0xb22222, 0x8b4513, 0xc00000);
        case ChartColorPalette.Excel:
           return GetColors(0x9999ff, 0x993366, 0xffffcc, 0xccffff, 0x660066, 0xff8080, 0x0066cc, 0xccccff, 0x000080, 0xff00ff, 0xffff00, 0x00ffff, 0x800080, 0x800000, 0x008080, 0x0000ff);
        case ChartColorPalette.Fire:
           return GetColors(0xffd700, 0xff0000, 0xff1493, 0xdc143c, 0xff8c00, 0xff00ff, 0xffff00, 0xff4500, 0xc71585, 0xdde221);
        case ChartColorPalette.Grayscale:
           return GetColors(0xc8c8c8, 0xbdbdbd, 0xb2b2b2, 0xa7a7a7, 0x9c9c9c, 0x919191, 0x868686, 0x7b7b7b, 0x707070, 0x656565, 0x5a5a5a, 0x4f4f4f, 0x444444, 0x393939, 0x2e2e2e, 0x232323);
        case ChartColorPalette.Light:
           return GetColors(0xe6e6fa, 0xfff0f5, 0xffdab9, 0xfffacd, 0xffe4e1, 0xf0fff0, 0xf0f8ff, 0xf5f5f5, 0xfaebd7, 0xe0ffff);
        case ChartColorPalette.Pastel:
           return GetColors(0x87ceeb, 0x32cd32, 0xba55d3, 0xf08080, 0x4682b4, 0x9acd32, 0x40e0d0, 0xff69b4, 0xf0e68c, 0xd2b48c, 0x8fbc8b, 0x6495ed, 0xdda0dd, 0x5f9ea0, 0xffdab9, 0xffa07a);
        case ChartColorPalette.SeaGreen:
           return GetColors(0x2e8b57, 0x66cdaa, 0x4682b4, 0x008b8b, 0x5f9ea0, 0x3cb371, 0x48d1cc, 0xb0c4de, 0xffffff, 0x87ceeb);
        case ChartColorPalette.SemiTransparent:
           return GetColors(0xff6969, 0x69ff69, 0x6969ff, 0xffff69, 0x69ffff, 0xff69ff, 0xcdb075, 0xffafaf, 0xafffaf, 0xafafff, 0xffffaf, 0xafffff, 0xffafff, 0xe4d5b5, 0xa4b086, 0x819ec1);
        case ChartColorPalette.None:
        default:
           return GetColors(0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0x000000);
     }
  }

  private static Color[] GetColors(params Int32[] values)
  {
     return values.Select(value => Color.FromArgb(255, Color.FromArgb(value))).ToArray(); // alpha channel of 255 for fully opaque
  }
 }
}
```

Hope this is useful to someone out there...